# How to bundle typescript files to single js file using Parcel Bundler?

Tags: typescript, package.json, parceljs

I am using a very basic setup to test the [Parcel Bundler](https://parceljs.org/getting_started.html), but I'm running into errors when trying to bundle all my Typescript files into one JS file.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "outFile" : "./dist/bundle.js",
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es5",
        "allowJs": true,
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

> Error: Only 'amd' and 'system' modules are supported alongside --outFile

But when I leave out `outFile : "./dist/bundle.js`, then all Typescript files get compiled to separate `.js` files

Changing the module setting to `system` or `amd` like the error suggests makes no sense. I don't use SystemJS or AMD, so these will generate errors in the browser:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: System
>
> TypeError: undefined is not a function (AMD)

How can I tell Parcel to bundle TS files into one JS file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using parcel the wrong way. When using parcel, you should using a single entry(a HTML for browser or a js for node)then run `parcel entry`, parcel will automatically output what you want.

From the description in the question, I'm guessing you're using `tsc`, which you should use alongside parcel. So `outFile` option is also not needed.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the tsconfig. There are still separate JS files when using `parcel serve` but it's now one file when using `parcel build`. One last question: do you know how to preserve the directory structure in the build folder? (Images in the assets folder, JS in the JS folder, CSS files in the CSS folder). Everything now gets placed in the root directory.

Comment: currently you cannot