# Parceljs How to create one bundle file instead of each file?

Tags: javascript, bundle, parceljs

I have a simple project setup with parcel:

```js
/** main.js */
console.log("Hey")
```

```js
/** tools.js */
console.log("Hoo")
```

When I run parcel it creates two files: **main.js** and **tools.js**. However I would love to have it bundle to one file where booth source codes are in it. Like this:

```js
/** bundle.js */
console.log("Hoo")
console.log("Hey")
```

How can I achieve this?

This is my build command `parcel build ./src/**/*.js`. The target environment is the browser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bundle typescript files to single js file using Parcel Bundler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55892979/how-to-bundle-typescript-files-to-single-js-file-using-parcel-bundler)